# delphi twebbrowser modify html before loaded

Tags: delphi, twebbrowser

Is is possible to modify the html before it is loaded/executed in the browser?

To add functions to a web site out of my control I want to change a javascript from the original to my own.

E.g: in the html the browser load I would like to change:

```
<script src="/java.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
to:
<script src="http://mysite/java.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I can not just load my own page as I need to login to the site for it to work and the site use cookies to check im logged in.

---

I load the modifyed code like this:

```
Var
  aStream     : TMemoryStream;

begin

if Assigned(WebBrowser1.Document) then 
begin       
aStream := TMemoryStream.Create;

try
     aStream.LoadFromFile(Root + 'main.htm');
     aStream.Seek(0, soFromBeginning);
     (WebBrowser1.Document as IPersistStreamInit).Load(TStreamAdapter.Create(aStream));
  finally
     aStream.Free;
     Timer1.Enabled := True;
  end;
  HTMLWindow2 := (WebBrowser1.Document as IHTMLDocument2).parentWindow;
end;
```

This used to work, but the site added a login and now the requests the javascript do get access denied. I have tried to navigate to the login and login before I load my own code, but I still get access denied.

Comment: Which platform? VCL/FM, also which version of Delphi do you have?

Answer (score 1):

In VCL, yes.  You can download the HTML yourself and  modify it as needed (you need to insert a `<base href>` tag specifying the original URL into the `<head>` if the HTML contains relative links).  Then navigate the browser to `about:blank`, query its `Document` for the `IPersistStreamInit` interface, and call its `load()` method, passing it the modified HTML using the VCL's `TStringStream` and `TStreamAdapter` classes.

In FMX, I have no clue.

Comment: Added to the first post.

Comment: @remy , can you please provide more detailed instructions about how to do it ? I saved the modified html and called it with navigate method, but the page loads without it CSS styles.

Comment: @delphirules: There are plenty of online forum ports and tutorials on how to load HTML data into `TWebBrowser` via `IPersistStreamInit`, if you look around. Does the HTML refer to CSS using an external file (and if so, does it use an absolute or relative URL to refer to that file)? Or is the CSS in the HTML itself?

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the approach:**

1. Create a pluggable MIME filter (refer to `IInternetProtocol`) to monitor HTML document (mime type `text/html`) before it is rendered by `TWebBrowser`.
2. Use regular expression to replace desired contents. In your case is to replace `src="/java.js"` with `src="http://mysite/java.js"`.

Here is a [code example.](http://read.pudn.com/downloads89/sourcecode/delphi_control/340555/OurMimeFilter.pas__.htm) And I highly suggest you read these documents first.

1. [About Asynchronous Pluggable Protocols](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767916%28v=VS.85%29.aspx#About_Pluggable_MIME)
2. http://www.44342.com/webbrowser-control-f125-t489-p1.htm
3. http://www.delphipraxis.net/60272-probleme-mit-plugable-protocol.html

Comment: I removed the previous answer of using `IDocHostUIHandler.TranslateURL`, because I think it might mislead other readers, if they are in a similar situation.

Comment: Thanks. I will look in to this, seems like the right approch.

Answer (score 0):

For now the problem are solved by adding another twebbrowser to the project. (On a new tab). This webbrowser handle the login and keep the required php session alive. (It is automatic keept alive as long as the window stay open). Now Im able to load my own modifyed code without access denied.

Thanks for all your help.